# findAll() Not Returning Correct Object Type

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm, findall

ItemTag objects contain an Item object and a Tag object. (These are Java domain objects.)

This simple query works as expected. I get back a list ItemTags and can do all the wonderful things that ItemTags are supposed to do:

```
def theTags1 = ItemTag.findAll("from ItemTag  b")
```

For example:

```
println(theTags1[0].tag.tag)
```

gives me this as expected:

```
Pilgrim's Progress
```

However, as soon as I add another table to the criteria, instead of getting a list of ItemTags, I just get a list of generic objects.

e.g the following

```
def theTags2 = ItemTag.findAll("from ItemTag  b, Tag a where b.tag= a")

theTags2.each {
     theClass = it.getClass();
     nameOfClass = theClass.getName();
     println(nameOfClass)
}
```

returns

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;
[Ljava.lang.Object;
[Ljava.lang.Object;
```

And I can't use the resulting objects at all. For example:

```
println(theTags2[0].tag.tag)
```

gives me this error:

```
Exception evaluating property 'tag' for java.util.ArrayList, Reason: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: tag for class: java.lang.String
```

and

```
def exTag2 = (ItemTag) theTags2[0]
```

gives me this error:

```
Cannot cast object '[Ljava.lang.Object;@2d81f' with class '[Ljava.lang.Object;' to class 'org.maflt.flashlit.pojo.ItemTag'
```

What do I need to do to get usable objects? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hibernate, the

> `"from ItemTag  b, Tag a where b.tag= a"`

query is a cross-join. The result of this query is a list of Object arrays where the first item is an ItemTag instance and the second is a Tag instance.

You have to use e.g.

> `(ItemTag) theTags2[0][0]`

to access the first ItemTag instance.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Just for the sake of completeness, to get a Tag, I use: 

(Tag) theTags2[0][1]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are just trying to get the ItemTag object you can also change the HQL to something like:

```
def theTags2 = ItemTag.findAll("select b from ItemTag  b, Tag a where b.tag= a")
```

That tells it you only want one object.
You should also be able to use a join condition I think something like:

```
def theTags2 = ItemTag.findAll("from ItemTag b where b.tag is not null")
```